# XAML Controls not responding after some time in UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have developed an application using **UWP**. After some usage of the application, TextBox controls are no longer responding. Is there anything we need to do with related to textboxes? Below is the code I am using for a textbox.

```
  <TextBox Name="txtCustomerMobileNumber" Background="White" Padding="10,3,0,0" PlaceholderText="Mobile" x:Uid="txtMobile" MaxLength="10" Grid.Column="0" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,0" KeyUp="txtCustomerMobileNumber_KeyUp" TextChanging="txtNoValidation_TextChanging" TabIndex="13"/>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the reproduce steps? And the code snippet about `txtCustomerMobileNumber_KeyUp` and `txtNoValidation_TextChanging`?

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?  Did you still need help?